# Difference between "choose" and "select"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, differences

These two words are often used interchangeably and the greatest difference I can find between the two is "choose" for choosing multiple items from a set, and "select" for selecting a single item from a set. Are there other qualifiers to consider and is this singular/plural distinction on the right track?

So, really, what *is* the difference between the two, if any?

Comment: I don't think so. There is really nothing strange in the thought of "selecting three items" from a list (for instance). The only distinction that comes to mind is context: one might be less inclined to say they "selected" the left fork in the road, but this has nothing to do with quantity...

Comment: horatio, if nothing to do with quantity, then what makes the distinction between the two, if any?

Comment: I would rather not say, because I haven't thought much about it (which is why I didn't make an answer). My instinct is that they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: I do agree with what others have said, but I would add that **select** can imply some notion of competition, while **choose** does not. For example, I would say *“Harvard selects the best students based on essays”*, and substituting *chooses* in that sentence would look bad.

Comment: Btw: this question is tagged word-*choice*

Comment: There is one case where there is an important difference between the two: when someone decides *whether or not do do something*: "She chose to quit her job."In this case "select" does not work. So I guess you can say, if it's a **binary** choice, use "choose"; otherwise, you can use either one.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Select* means *to carefully choose*; it also means *to use a mouse or keystrokes to mark something on a computer screen*.

In both the cases, the number of things chosen or marked does not influence which verb is used.

Comment: I think this is indeed the case, *selecting* something seems more well thought over then *choosing* something. Choosing seems more random then selecting.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to what you said,

According to [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

**Select** is ***more formal*** than **choose**, and in everyday English, people usually say choose rather than select.

Also there's a homophone for choose which is [chews](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chews).

According to Merriam-Webster

- **choose**: *to have a preference for*  or *to select freely and after consideration*
- **select**: *to choose (as by fitness or excellence) from a number or group*

I checked some other sources. In all of them the difference between select and choose is not considered important. so I think maybe it's a better idea not to be fussy about it!

Comment: note also that "a choice [item]" means "a [really good] [premium] [excellent] [carefully selected] item" which (again) points to a very strong similarity in meaning and usage.

Answer (score -2):

Selection is done after evaluation of some qualities of something.

Choose is done based on self interest and preference about something.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing facts and references that demonstrate its correctness.