# Is there a difference between "opt" and "choose"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

Could you give examples where one is better suited than the other one? Or are they completely synonymous?

<sup>(I'm not a native speaker.)</sup>

**Update:** I'm writing a piece software documentation and I wonder if it's better to use *choose* or *opt*:

> ... Note that these components can receive input themselves (although they may **opt/choose** not to). ...

Comment: Hi, Petr. As it stands, this question is "general reference", because it's easy to find the answer in a good dictionary. To improve it, you need to give us more details: what specific context were you thinking of using either word? After looking up the words in a dictionary, what are you still not clear about? (It's entirely possible to look things up in a dictionary and end up more confused than you started. Been there, done that.) Also, since you're asking this *because* you're not a native speaker, have you considered asking it on ell.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Marthaª Thanks for the suggestion, I added where I need to use one of the words. My previous searches lead me to believe that they're interchangeable, but I wanted to be sure. As of _ell_, how do I decide if I should ask here or there? For example, I found a similar question to mine here: [Difference between “choose” and “select”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13039/28975).

Comment: I suggested ELL because you found it necessary to mention that you're not a native speaker, which might mean that you're facing this question *because* you're learning English. If that's not actually the case, then certainly, this type of word-choice question is quite welcome here. (Although note that when the older question was asked, ELL didn't exist yet.)

Comment: About your update: I don't think I'd use an active word like "opt" *or* "choose" with an inanimate subject like "components". I'm not sure what I'd replace it with; I'd probably rewrite the whole section to avoid this sort of personification in what is presumably a technical document.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by *recieve input*?

Comment: @Marthaª Thanks for your valuable comments. Next time I'll use ELL instead. | Is it always incorrect to use active verbs like "opt" with inanimate subjects? For example, is "a robot chose something" incorrect? (Would this question be more appropriate for this site or for ELL?) I guess programmers tend to personify software because of its complex behavior, without realizing it is often incorrect from the language point of view (regardless of which language they use).

Comment: @brick I'm not sure how to describe it without going into technical details (and personification :)). In my particular example, a SW component can be viewed as component in an assembly line. At each step the component can "decide" to either request (input) another item from its preceding component, or send a processed item to its succeeding component. In my case, it's possible that a component never requests any input item (which is completely legal behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/opt):

> **Choose** is the most general of these words and the only one that can be used without an object. When you *select* something, you choose it carefully, unless you actually say that it is selected randomly/at random. *Pick* is a more informal word and often a less careful action, used especially when the choice being made is not very important.

While

> **Opt** - to choose to take or not to take a particular course of action:
>
> After graduating she **opted** for a career in music. 
>     After a lot of thought, I **opted** against buying a motorbike.

---

As for your sentence I would suggest using something like *input may be discarded/declined by the component(-s)*.

Comment: Why the strikethrough?

Comment: I wanted to put stress on *Choose*. But didn't want to exclude explanations on *to select* and *to pick* verbs usage.

Comment: But that's not what strikethrough means: it implies that the struck-through text is somehow incorrect, or has been superseded.